# Proof by induction; simplify when adding k+1th term. Understanding induction.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I want to prove:

$$(-\frac{1}{2})^0 + (-\frac{1}{2})^1 + \cdots + (-\frac{1}{2})^k + (-\frac{1}{2})^{k+1}
=
\frac{2^{k+1}+(-1^k)}{3\cdot2^k} + (-\frac{1}{2})^{k+1}$$

How do I simplify the last bit, $\frac{2^{k+1}+(-1^k)}{3\cdot2^k} + (-\frac{1}{2})^{k+1}$, so I don't have a case of $a+b$ ?

Additionally, how is this considered a proof? I've looked up on Wikipedia re: induction, and the example they gave went something like "if the base case is true, assume $P(k)$ is true, and if $P(k+1)$ holds, then $P(k)$ is true".

I don't make much sense of this. How do I know if $P(k+1)$ holds? On Wikipedia they simplified $P(k+1)$ and then directly said it holds without reasoning from what I can tell. Essentially Wikipedia stated the following:

1. Check if $P(0)$ or $P(1)$ is true
2. Let $k$ be an arbitrary number
3. Assume $P(k)$ is true
4. Simplify $P(k+1)$
5. $P(k+1)$ holds because we simplified it <-- this is where I'm tripping up.

How do I show that $P(k+1)$ holds?

Comment: Please give us the statement that you're trying to prove. What is P(K)? It should look something like $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^k = \frac{\ldots}{\ldots}$$

Comment: $$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k} \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^j = \frac{2^{k+1}+(-1)^k}{3*2^k}$$

The base case, $P(0)$ holds, but I'm not sure how to check if $P(k)$ or $P(k+1)$ hold. $k\in\mathbb{z^+}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's follow your steps.  $P(0)\iff \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^0=\frac{2^1+(-1)^{0}}{3\times2^{0}}=\frac{3}{3}=1$, which is true.

Now, assume $P(k)$ is true.  Then $S_k:=\sum_{n=0}^k \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=\frac{2^{k+1}+(-1)^{k}}{3\cdot 2^k}$.
$$\begin{align}S_{k+1}&=S_k+\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}\\
&=\frac{2^{k+1}+(-1)^{k}}{3\cdot 2^k}+\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}\\
&=\frac{2^{k+2}+2(-1)^{k}}{3\cdot 2^{k+1}}+\frac{3(-1)^{k+1}}{3\cdot 2^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac{2^{k+2}-2(-1)^{k+1}+3(-1)^{k+1}}{3\cdot 2^{k+1}}\\
&=\frac{2^{k+2}+(-1)^{k+1}}{3\cdot 2^{k+1}}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, under the assumption $P(k)$, $P(k+1)$ is true. Since we know $P(0)$ is true, $P(n)$ must be true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$.